# .htaccess redirect from root( public_html ) to subdirectory and deny direct access to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

M1:
This works to redirect from root to subdirectory

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html
```

M2:
This works to deny direct access to root

.htaccess in the root( public_html )

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

then using this allows direct access to the subdirectory

.htaccess in the subdirectory

```
Allow from all
```

## website structure

```
public_html
     |___ subdirectory ___ index.php
     |___ .htaccess
     |___ app
     |___ something.php
```

when i add them both example.com gives

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

first time changing any thing in .htaccess

## edit

what i want to do is block direct access to anything but the subdirectory.

also if

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1 [NC]
```

will conflict with it if added to the subdirectory

Comment: Unclear what you want. Do you want to block access to `app` folder only or anything except `subdirectory` ?

Comment: anything but subdirectory @anubhava

Comment: the subdirectory will contain the index.php,css, js and img anything that have to be direct accessed @anubhava

Comment: Should `example.com/something.php` be allowed?

Comment: no, Only the subdirectory can be accessed directly  anything else internal like includes and requests with PHP @anubhava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# for example.com rewrite landing page to subdirectory/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]

# for example.com rewrite all other URIs to subdirectory/uri
# (?!subdirectory/) is a negative lookahead that stops rewrite then uri 
# already starts with /subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!subdirectory/)(.+)$ subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks it works, does this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1 [NC]`
 conflict with any of the above@anubhava

Comment: Yes it will conflict. What is purpose of that rule? That rule should probably be placed in `subdirectory/.htaccess`

Comment: also, can you please explain what every line does @anubhava

Comment: yes it will be added there but I don't know how .htaccess works@anubhava

Comment: You have to write **all** the requirements in question. Before posting I clarified as well.

Comment: is there a site where  I can learn more about .htaccess, thanks again @anubhava